# Undesired Output

Tags: c++, string, string-length

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string a, b;
    int number_cases=0,i,j,count=0;
    cin>>number_cases;
    while(number_cases!=0)
        {
            cin>>a;
            cin>>b;
            for(i=0;i<a.size();i++) {
                for(j=0;j<b.size();j++) {
                    if(a[i]==b[j]); {
                        count++;
                        b[j]='#';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            cout<<count<<endl;
            count=0;
            --number_cases;
        }
}
```

http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/LCPESY
I am getting TLE  error on submiting , suggest some ways to optimise output.

Comment: Please do not remove errors from your code, if they are discussed in the answers below. This makes it harder for other people to learn from your mistakes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is lacking the minimal understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The only mistake is

```
if(a[i]==b[j]);
```

Remove ";" from if statement

```
if(a[i]==b[j])
```

It'll work fine

Comment: i noticed it , 
fix the TLE problem

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string a, b;
```

Since you write using namespace std the "std::" is not nessecary.

But the reason your program doesn't work is since you have a ";" in your if statement.

```
if(a[i]==b[j]);
```

Should be

```
if(a[i]==b[j])
```